# Baffled by itertools groupby summation

Tags: python

Consider this...

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [{'pid': 1, 'items': 1}, {'pid': 2, 'items': 5}, {'pid': 1, 'items': 3}]
data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('pid'))

for pid, rows in groupby(data, lambda x: x['pid']):
    print(pid, sum(r['items'] for r in rows))
    for key in ['items']:
        print(pid, sum(r[key] for r in rows))
```

The first `print()` call prints the right #, 4 for `pid` 1, 5 for 2. The second `print()` call, in the loop through the key list, prints 0 for both. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rows` object you get from `groupby` is a type of generator that can only be consumed once. As you iterate through it for your first print statement, you consume the values, and thus `rows` is an empty generator when you try to iterate over it the next time -- you've already visited and used up your access to its iteration abilities.

You could use `row_list = list(rows)` then use `row_list` if you want the items to be persistent for multiple iteration passes.

For greater clarity, I suggest putting your code into the Python REPL and inspecting `type(rows)` in that loop, and looking at what API that object provides.

Comment: Ah yeah. i guess this is also why generators fail when using them inside list comprehensions. Neat little lesson.

Comment: Generators implement the Iterator Protocol, so they do not fail when used in a list comprehension. On the contrary, it's precisely the sort of pattern that generators were intended for. Using `row_list = [r for r in rows]` is effectively identical to `row_list = list(rows)` for a generator object `rows` as in your example.

Answer (score 3):

You're running into a very common issue with generators - that they can only be iterated through once. `itertools` returns generators as a rule.

From the [docs for `groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with `groupby()`. Because the source is shared, when the `groupby()` object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.

Simply remove one of your `print()` calls, and watch it work. If you need to access the returned data multiple times, a list is a potential structure to save your results in.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed code:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [{'pid': 1, 'items': 1}, {'pid': 2, 'items': 5}, {'pid': 1, 'items': 3}]
data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('pid'))

for pid, rows_gen in groupby(data, lambda x: x['pid']):
    rows=list(rows_gen)      # save the group to access more than once
    print(pid, sum(r['items'] for r in rows))
    for key in ['items']:
        print(pid, sum(r[key] for r in rows))
```